# javascript map object multidimension

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, object, ecmascript-6

i have this data structure:

```
tree = [
  {
    "name": "Men Section",
    "categories": [
       {
         "name": "Clothings",
         "Subcategories": [
            {
              "name": "Jackets",
              "products": [
                 {
                    "name": "jacket 01",
                    "price": 100
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "jacket 02",
                    "price": 140
                 },
                 // ..and so on
              ]
         ]
       },
       // ..and so on
    ]
  } // ..and so on
]
```

how can i add new property in products item `isSelected: false` in javascript (ES5 or ES6 is fine) so the object will be

```
{
  "name": "jacket 01",
  "price": 100,
  "isSelected": false
}
```

?

Comment: Need to loop through all the arrays to get to each product. Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service

Comment: The quickest method is `tree.categories[0].subCategories[0].products[0].isSelected = false` but your question isn't very high on details so I'd imagine that's not the answer you want.

Comment: this kind of answer i would like to hear.

Comment: Er, that's it. You have a bunch of nested arrays. Just target the path you need.

Comment: i was thinking about map inside map but i guess it's cannot be done

Comment: If your question is anything other than "I want to updated the first object in the products array of the first element in the subCategories array of the first element in the products array" you need to re-edit your question with more details using a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be useful, it works for me

```
tree.forEach(base => {
  base.categories.forEach(categories => {
    categories.Subcategories.forEach(subCategory =>{
      subCategory.products.forEach(product => product.isSelected = false)
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so yeah, i should traverse deep to the object with nested foreach. i came up with this:

```
tree.categories.forEach(function (category) {
  category.subcategories.forEach(function (subcategory) {
    subcategory.products.forEach(function (product) {
        product.isSelected = false;
    })
  })
})
```

thanks for the enlightment